# Unable to launch Firefox driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have Firefox 11 in my Win7 system with selenium 24.1:

When I tried to launch Firefox using from Eclipse, I got following error(It's same for all even after re installation ):

```
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.layoutOnDisk(FirefoxProfile.java:389)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.fire fox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)at mend.w.main(w.java:9)
```

Following is the code, I tried:

```
package try;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class trySelenium {
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    FirefoxDriver n = new FirefoxDriver();
    n.get("google.com");
  }
}
```

Comment: forgot to add the code:

package try;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
public class trySelenium {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
FirefoxDriver n = new FirefoxDriver();
n.get("http://google.com");}}

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using selenium 2.41, it will not support Firefox 11. Either upgrade your browser or downgrade selenium version to respective supported Firefox version.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
FirefoxDriver n = new FirefoxDriver();
```

use following in your code:

```
WebDriver n = new FirefoxDriver();
```

`WebDriver` is an interface that `FirefoxDriver` class is implementing.

Comment: I used the same but it ddnt work so added this as well:           File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Maverick\\Desktop\\IEDriverServer.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());                                                                                                                 and the it worked fine with your suggestion but now i am geting a new error                                                                Failed to load the library from temp directory